# Why not test androids by asking them to hold their breath?

Tags: androids, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

In Dick's **"Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"** we learn that androids can commit suicide by holding their breath:

> "How'll you kill yourself without it?" Rick asked. "If you fail on the test?
>
> "I'll hold my breath."
>
> "Chrissake," Rick said. "It can't be done."
>
> "There's no automatic cut-in of the vagus nerve," Phil Resch said, "in an android. As there is in a human. Weren't you taught that when they trained you? I got taught that years ago."
>
> "But to die that way," Rick protested.
>
> "There's no pain. What's the matter with it?"

Then, Rick Deckard obtains a weapon that can temporarily stun androids by stopping them breathing. It's said that while it also works against humans, they can stay conscious without breathing for a while, long enough to give them a distinct advantage.

So, why not to test androids this way instead of using the Voight-Kampff or other empathy tests? Or is that weapon is supposed to be a fake, gave to Rick only to make him fail his mission?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An Android can hold their breath to prove that they ARE an android, because a human cannot fake holding their breath for ever.

An Android cannot use this technique to prove that they are NOT an android, because they can fake the gasp.

Comment: I like this answer more than the other one because it's based on the motivation an androidone has to take any test - to prove he is/isn't a human/android.

Comment: You could developp on how/why one would fake being a human/android with the Voight-Kampff test though.

Answer (score 16):

The "hold your breath until you die" trick seems to only work if there's a conscious intention to commit suicide.

Deckard later makes it clear that while an 'andy' might lack as ***dramatic*** a vagus response as a normal human, they certainly have one.

> "Is this it?" He held up a metallic sphere with a button-stem
>   projecting.
>
> "That cancels an android into catalepsy," Rachael said, her eyes shut.
>   "For a few seconds. Suspends its respiration; yours, too, but humans
>   can function without respiring — perspiring? —for a couple of minutes,
>   but the vagus nerve of an andy — "
>
> "I know." He straightened up. "**The android autonomic nervous system
>   isn't as flexible at cutting in and out as ours.** But as you say, this wouldn't work for more than five or six seconds."

---

As far as using it as a test is concerned, asking an android to hold their breath until they lose consciousness would be totally pointless since they could simply fake a gasp.

Using Rachel's device to render the andy unconscious would be similarly pointless since androids *do have* a vagus response and would start breathing shortly after being zapped.

At best, you'd be able to use this test to rule out those people who have an *above average* gasp response.

---

As to the second part of your question, there's no good evidence that Rachel's device is a fake. It appears to simply be a miniaturised version of his own "[Penrose wave transmitter](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=130)";

> Best to get him from out here, he decided. Setting down his weapons
>   kit he fumbled it open, got out a nondirectional Penfield wave
>   transmitter; he punched the key for catalepsy, himself protected
>   against the mood emanation by means of a counterwave broadcast through
>   the transmitter's metal hull directed to him alone.